# Replace non-numeric values as truly missing in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, missing-data

I want to use the data analysis toolpack (and perform other analyses) on data which (unintentionally) have strings where there should be numbers.  For example, I might have a column:

```
0,
1,
don't know,
7
```

I use the following statement to generate a new column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,"")
```

Returning:

```
0,
1,
"",
7
```

I'm unable to do data analysis on these because of the "".  However, if I just type the following into cells skipping the third row, I am able to do analysis:

```
0,
1,
,
7
```

Any tips on how to properly do this replacement using missing values is appreciated.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Apply your above formula to the range of data.
2. Copy and **paste special as values** entire column with formula to the same range.
3. Apply autofilter (better have column header for this above the data).
4. Filter only `(Blanks)`.
5. Select all filtered cells and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or select `Clear Contents` from the right-click menu.

Thus you'll get the new list that match your requirements. A bit straightforward, but will go) Good luck!